# MouseLeave fires on child Elements in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, electron

I am handling mouse hover events using the following HTML template and script. My app is written using AngularJS and hosted in Electron.

HTML:

```
<div id="controlArea" 
     (mouseenter) = "onControlAreaEnter()" 
     (mouseleave) = "onControlAreaLeave($event)">
    <div id="moveArea" *ngIf="controlsVisible">
        <img src="assets/Icons/move.png" height="32" width="32"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
 onControlAreaEnter(){
    this.controlsVisible = true;
 }
 onControlAreaLeave(event){    
    this.controlsVisible = false;
 }
```

When I view my app through chrome mouseleave is only fired when I leave the controlArea div. However when I put my app into electron mouseleave is fired when I hover onto the child div element. Is there a way to prevent this from happening in Electron?

Comment: the version of angular? does it work right the first time you hover over?

Comment: Angular4. Events fire correctly when entering and leaving the controlArea but when you hover over any child element of the Control Area the mouseleaving Event fires again when it should not.

Comment: i think you can just add to those functions ```event.stopPropagation();```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot figure out a way to only stop mouseleave propagation for controlArea when moving over a child element and allow propagation when actually leaving ControlArea.

Comment: why not do it over moveArea id or time for a custom directive.

Answer (score 1):

Using a current workaround to filter out leave events when they occur inside the controlArea. This however doesn't explain why leave events are occuring on child elements in Electron.

```
 onControlAreaLeave(event){
    // Check to see if we went to a child element 
    // Only need this because of Electron otherwise it works fine in browsers
    if (event.clientX > 4 && 
        event.clientX < window.innerWidth && 
        event.clientY > 4 && 
        event.clientY < this.controlArea.nativeElement.offsetHeight) {
       return;
    }

    this.controlsVisible = false;
  }
```